# Visual Studio errors disappear when open file

Tags: c#, roslyn, visual-studio-2022

I'm in the process of updating a library in a larger solution. For this purpose, I have removed the old references in all projects and added new ones.

If I compile the solution now I get about 3000 build errors, which indicate that various classes are defined in the old, removed libraries and I should add a reference to them.

After I have opened a reported file, Visual Studio recognizes that these classes are also included in the new libraries and removes the error.

Now I don't want to open hundreds of files to make these ghost errors disappear, especially because the problem repeats itself after the next build.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get Visual Studio to stop reporting ghost bugs?

I'm using Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: C#? VB.NET? C++? TypeScript? Keep in mind no other here can see your screen, so edit the question to include enough details (or screen shots if it is difficult to describe clearly).

Comment: Sorry, its a solution with C# Projecta. But it seems to me to be more an VS issue than a language problem.

Comment: Clean the solution, remove bin and obj directories, restart Visual Studio, remove the .vs directory?

Comment: Try to close Visual Studio and delete .vs folder in project location, it should work.
Take a look at this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/57519860/3559462

Comment: While you might feel like it is a VS issue, different languages use different technologies behind the scene to enable code analysis and error reporting. By knowing you are working on C# projects, I can then add two more tags and experts in those areas can take a look. Make sure you select the correct tags for your future questions here.

Comment: For VS 2022 caching is a common issue. see what @-CodeCaster said